# Event Source timeout in 45 seconds

Tags: javascript, frontend, server-sent-events, connection-timeout

I am working on eventSource where I get percentage from backend. To implement that I have used
[Event source pollyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-source-polyfill)

My problem is backend is taking some time(2 to 3 mins) to respond. But at the front end the eventSource API is failing stating -

```
No activity within 45000 milliseconds. Reconnecting
```

To fix that I tried [this solution](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/issues/193#issuecomment-926393906). But no matter what changes I make in eventSource.js in node_modules they are not reflecting.

Can somebody please look.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "My problem is backend is taking some time(2 to 3 mins) to respond." That is indeed your problem, so why are you trying to fix a symptom of that problem? Is someone else in charge of the backend? Are you doing extremely heavy calculations that makes it impossible to reduce the response time? Why is the response time so extremely long?

Comment: You don't need any polyfills: [**all** modern browsers have native support for SSE](https://caniuse.com/eventsource) excepting IE, but I'm skeptical that you actually need to support IE11...

Comment: @EmilKarlsson operations are like fetching all the records from different tables to show in one table. (thats the requirement). It is difficult to reduce that time as of now. But how can I increase the timeout from 45 seconds to 3 mins or close to it?

Comment: @Dai I am using eventSourcePollyfill because it allows me to send Authorization header. I am not sure if simple eventSource allows us to send headers.

Comment: You shouldn't normally need to use the `Authorization` header with SSE endpoints - and cookies work just fine.

Comment: but I want to pass some headers the native event source did not support. @Dai

Comment: But my whole site Authorization using header, just one request with sse using cookie? seems wired. @Dai

Comment: @Dolphin I don't understand what you're trying to say, sorry. (But in general, you can pass extra data via query-string parameters; if you need to pass large amounts of data (e.g. a POST body) then you could have a separate handler that receives the extra data and keeps it in-memory and returns a short reference string, while the SSE client sends that short reference string as a query parameter which your SSE endpoint will use.

Comment: it seems a good solution, I want to pass header with my jwt token, but the evnet source did not support header. I do not want the token expose to the url by using query string, seems get a short temp token is a good solution. @Dai

Answer (score 2):

Set `options.hearbeatTimeout` to a very large number.
E.g. `10 * 60 * 1000` would make it 10 minutes. (The `45000` is just the default.)

To show it is possible, I found an example for doing that in Vue here: https://github.com/tserkov/vue-sse/issues/35#issuecomment-986807802

---

BTW, there should be no need to hack the source, when an option is already supplied. I've had mixed luck modifying the files in node_modules - they risk getting replaced without notice. Better is to make a branch on github, modify it there, and change your entry in package.json to link to that:

```
"the_package": "github:YourName/the_package#master",
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> put two minutes instead of 45 seconds, you need to add heartbeatTimeout: 120000, in your options
> ```

```
 const sse = new EventSourcePolyfill(`yourURL`,
                        {
                                    headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
                                        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                                        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                                        'X-Accel-Buffering': 'no',
                                        Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                                    },
                                    heartbeatTimeout: 120000,
                                    withCredentials: true,
                                });
                
                            sse.onmessage = (e) => {
                                console.log(e);
                            }
                            sse.onerror = (event) => {
                                console.log(event);
                                sse.close();
                            }
```

Comment: This works for me. The easy way.